# Calculating total daily time in a spreadsheet with time ranges per cell

Tags: google-sheets, time

I have a basic spreadsheet to keep track of time spent on an activity.

The idea is to capture a time range per cell. E.g. `10:00 - 12:30` means 2 hours and 30 minutes.

Breaks can be taken during the day. On resuming, a new time range is entered in a new cell.

I want to calculate the total time per day. E.g. Mon Jun 15 is `2.5 + 4.5 = 7 hours`.

[image: spreadsheet with time ranges]

The algorithm I'm thinking of is more or less

```
for each cell that contains time ranges for the given day
  start, end = split(cell, " - ")
  diff_decimal = (end - start) * 24
  total += diff_decimal
```

But I'm not sure how to do this with spreadsheet functions.
The starting point I have is using `=SPLIT(B2," - ")` but I'm already blocked since I'm not sure how to handle the return value.

P.S. The problem could be simplified by having multiple "start" and "end" columns with one value per cell. But I want to try the given format, which I prefer, before trying another approach.

Comment: Very crude, but in `G2` you could try: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--(RIGHT(B2:F2,LEN(B2:F2)-FIND("-",B2:F2))),0))-SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--(LEFT(B2:F2,FIND(" ",B2:F2))),0))`. Format `G2` properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Google Sheets solution, as Excel does not have regex formulas.

Try this formula (place it in `G1`, column `G:G` formatted as number):

```
={
  "Total";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      A2:A = "",
        "",
        MMULT(
          IFERROR(
            (  TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:F, "-\s+(\S+)"))
             - TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:F, "(\S+)\s+-"))) * 24,
            0
          ),
          SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:F), 1, 1, 0)
        )  
    )
  )
}
```

If you format `G:G` as Duration then you can remove `* 24` part.

[image]

**UPD**

Added ignoring of the wrong formatted cells with `IFERROR` - just 0 in this case.

Better add this custom conditional formatting rule for `B2:F` to mark (in red on the screenshot) time periods in the wrong format and go fix them:

```
=AND(B2 <> "", NOT(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(B2, "\b(\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\s*-\s*(\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\b"), False)))
```

Comment: This is promising, but on my sheet gives the `G` cells below `G1` a value of #N/A with error: Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "-\s+(\S+)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value " ".

On the sheet, `B2:F` has time ranges, but they don't seem to be extracted correctly. Could it be a formatting issue? I tried formatting `B2:F` as plain text but no difference.

Comment: @Dennis regarding the error - you have non empty cells (with spaces) which are not ignored and `REGEXEXTRACT` fails. Let me correct for that case...